# Store CTR Centra in MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet

I have bought some CTR Centra from Cryptopia Exchange and I want to store them in MyEtherWallet. 
How do I do that

Answer (score 1):

CTR is an ERC20 token, which MyEtherWallet supports. You just need to add the CTR token in the right of your wallet screen - https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/send/adding-new-token-and-sending-custom-tokens.html

Within Cryptopia, withdraw the CTR tokens by sending them to your public address that you use with MyEtherWallet, then add the token to the GUI (so the GUI can perform lookups as I don't think it's in the default token list)

- Address: `0x96A65609a7B84E8842732DEB08f56C3E21aC6f8a`
- Symbol: `CTR`
- Decimals: `18`

[image]

[image]